# MySQL in clause slow with 10 or more items

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, in-clause

This query takes 18 seconds

```
SELECT `wd`.`week` AS `start_week`, `wd`.`hold_code`, COUNT(wd.hold_code) AS hold_code_count
FROM `weekly_data` AS `wd`
JOIN aol_reporting_hold_codes hc ON hc.hold_code = wd.hold_code AND chart = 'GR'
WHERE `wd`.`days` <= 6 
AND `wd`.`hold_code` IS NOT NULL 
AND NOT `wd`.`hold_code` = '' 
AND `wd`.`week` >= '201717' 
AND `wd`.`itemgroup` IN ('BOTDTO', 'BOTDWG', 'C&FORG', 'C&FOTO', 'MF-SUB', 'MI-SUB', 'PROPRI', 'PROPTO', 'STRSTO', 'STRSUB') 
AND `production_type` = 2
AND `contract` = "1234"
AND `project` = 8
GROUP BY `start_week`, `wd`.`hold_code`
```

This query takes 4 seconds

```
SELECT `wd`.`week` AS `start_week`, `wd`.`hold_code`, COUNT(wd.hold_code) AS hold_code_count
FROM `weekly_data` AS `wd`
JOIN aol_reporting_hold_codes hc ON hc.hold_code = wd.hold_code AND chart = 'GR'
WHERE `wd`.`days` <= 6 
AND `wd`.`hold_code` IS NOT NULL 
AND NOT `wd`.`hold_code` = '' 
AND `wd`.`week` >= '201717' 
AND `wd`.`itemgroup` IN ('BOTDWG', 'C&FORG', 'C&FOTO', 'MF-SUB', 'MI-SUB', 'PROPRI', 'PROPTO', 'STRSTO', 'STRSUB') 
AND `production_type` = 2
AND `contract` = "1234"
AND `project` = 8
GROUP BY `start_week`, `wd`.`hold_code`
```

All I have done is removed one item from the IN clause. I can remove any one of the items. It runs in 4 seconds as long as there are 9 items or less. It takes 18 seconds to run as soon as I increase to 10 items.

I thought MySQL limited length of command by size i.e. 1MB

Comment: Did you check the execution plan?

Comment: We'll need to know the execution plan (and it would help to know the indexes, too.) It's quite possible that changing the query slightly is resulting in a different execution plan. My guess would be you're missing an index on `weekly_data.itemgroup`, though, but why it's taking so long would depend on the data and the indexes on the other columns used for search criteria.

Comment: @MattGibson Thank you, I just ran explain and found that with 9 option in my IN clause the keys used are
"contract,project__idx,production_type" When I add the tenth the key is simply itemgroup. Not sure what the solution is, I do have a key on itemgroup already. I might remove and re add it, unless there is any other better suggestion.

Comment: I wouldn't remove and re-add the index. You need to figure out why the optimiser is guessing wrong; it could be that statistics need refreshing, or you might just be better off adding another, more appropriate index, but what that index would be depends on your data.

Comment: (One thing to consider at this stage: which individual parts of your `WHERE` clause would narrow down the results the most? i.e. which of your comparisons filters out the largest numbers of rows from the potential full result set? Do you have appropriate indexes for those? For example, if you don't have an index on `week` but your table has ten years' worth of data in it, then you may be focusing on the wrong problem :D)

Answer (score 0):

More than just the `EXPLAIN`, use `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` and get the "Optimizer trace" for the query.  I suspect the length of the `IN` leads to picking a different query plan.

There is virtually no limit to the number of items in `IN`.  I have seen as many as 70K.

That aside, you may be able to speed up even the 4-sec version...

I suggest having this index.  Grrr... I can't tell which columns are in which tables.  So, if these are all in one table, then make such an index:

```
INDEX(production_type, contract, project) -- in any order
```

If those are all in `wd`, then tack on a 4th column - any of `week`, `itemgroup`, `days`.

Be cautious about `COUNT(wd.hold_code)`.

- `COUNT(x)` checks `x` for being non-`NULL`; is that what you want?  If not, then simply say `COUNT(*)`.
- When `JOINing`, then `GROUP BY`, you get an "explode-implode".  The number of intermediate rows is big; that is when the `COUNT` is performed.
- It seems wrong to both `COUNT(hold_code)` and `GROUP BY hold_code`.  What are you trying to do?

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score -1):

Please note MySql IN clause limit is established with max_allowed_packet value. You may check with NOT IN if results are faster. Also I suggest put values to be checked with IN clause under a buffer string instead of comma separated values and then give a try.